# What happens if a collector doesn't respond to a debt validation request?

Tags: united-states, debt-collection, new-york

After a debt collector sends you a notice, you have 30 days to respond. If you communicate to them that you want to have the debt validated and they haven't responded over a month later, either about the verification request or collection attempts, what can you do?

Are they *required* to respond to verification requests, or can they gather information on their side and go straight to suing you?

If they are required to do so, what is the time limit for that, and what penalties are there if they don't?

Comment: Do you actually _owe_ a debt that might have gone to collections? Or are you implying that the debt collector is a troll who is trying to fool or harass you into paying money that you actually do not owe? Third alternative: you were disputing a charge on a credit card, the credit card company sided with the merchant and demanded payment but you have no intention of paying because you believe that you don't morally owe the money regardless of what anyone says?

Comment: I plead the 5th on that. But let's assume a scenario where the debt is legit and the debtor is exercising all of his legal rights.

Comment: If the debt is legitimate, then the question of what debt collectors can and cannot do is one of law, not personal finance.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I think we're interested in such consumer issues here too, though.  Refer to http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/597/shall-we-broaden-the-allowed-topics-to-include-consumer-issues-protection

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea The OP acknowledges in a comment that the debt is legitimate and the debtor is exercising his legal rights. The issue thus seems to be one of how to avoid paying up for as long as possible e.g. by demanding verification that the debt is valid, with a hint of a possible countersuit (or report to the FTC? Consumer Protection Agency?) against the collector if it did not follow the letter of the law regarding responses to such requests, and then asking what the letter of the law is. I feel this is inappropriate. However, I did not down-vote the question, though I did vote to close it.

Comment: It's entirely within a debtor's right to request verification. The burden of proof is 100% on them. I don't feel sorry for them at all, and one would be foolish to roll over without a fight.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Noted. While I won't question this OP's intentions, I'll remark there are cases where a debt is claimed from someone who, while they may have intended to transact, have a valid reason after the fact to withhold payment (e.g. broken service contract condition, receipt of faulty or damaged goods, etc.) I think consumers who contest a debt from such a perspective would be interested in the answers to this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Debt collectors are *required* to validate the debt and send you verification *within five days of their initial communication with you.* The [Fair Debt Collections Practices Act](http://www.ftc.gov/os/statutes/fdcpa/fdcpact.shtm#809) (FDCPA), section 809 (**Validation of Debts**), subsection a) lays this out clearly:

> a) Within five days after the initial communication with a consumer in connection with the collection of any debt, a debt collector shall, unless the following information is contained in the initial communication or the consumer has paid the debt, send the consumer a written notice containing:
>
> 1. the amount of the debt
> 2. the name of the creditor to whom the debt is owed
> 3. a statement that unless the consumer, within thirty days after receipt of the notice, disputes the validity of the debt, or any portion thereof, the debt will be assumed to be valid by the debt collector
> 4. a statement that **if the consumer notifies the debt collector in writing within the thirty-day period that the debt, or any portion thereof, is disputed, the debt collector will obtain verification of the debt or a copy of a judgment against the consumer and a copy of such verification or judgment will be mailed to the consumer by the debt collector**
> 5. a statement that, upon the consumer's written request within the thirty-day period, the debt collector will provide the consumer with the name and address of the original creditor, if different from the current creditor.

However, if you notify them in writing to dispute the debt, the debt collector has to stop collection of the debt and send you written verification of it (which they already should have anyway). Per the act:

> b) If the consumer notifies the debt collector in writing within the thirty-day period described in subsection (a) that the debt ... is disputed, or that the consumer requests the name and address of the original creditor, **the debt collector shall cease collection of the debt ...  until the debt collector obtains verification of the debt or any copy of a judgment**, or the name and address of the original creditor, and a copy of such verification or judgment, or name and address of the original creditor, is mailed to the consumer by the debt collector.
>
> c) The failure of a consumer to dispute the validity of a debt under this section may not be construed by any court as an admission of liability by the consumer.

As for debt collectors that don't follow the act, [section 813](http://www.ftc.gov/os/statutes/fdcpa/fdcpact.shtm#813) (**Civil Liability**), lays out the consequences clearly. I won't quote it because it's a little long, but it's important to realize that per the title, these are **civil penalties.** That means they normally require a suit to be filed against the debt collector; if you read this section of the act, you can readily see that the penalties will occur *as the result of civil legal action.*

In short, yes, the debt collector is required to send you verification within a short time period after initially informing you. If they don't, **you need to talk to a lawyer** if you feel civil action is the best recourse. Since I'm not a lawyer, I can't, and don't, pretend to provide any meaningful legal advice.

**Side note:** I should add that one [criticism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_Debt_Collection_Practices_Act#By_consumer_groups) of the FDCPA is that it limits the civil penalties the court can award an individual, above and beyond the damages caused by the debt collection agency, to $1,000. The act was passed in 1977, so inflation has reduced the real amount and purchasing power of that award.